# scrapy_splash: scrape non-html content

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I wrote a spider which would scrape web pages and later I would convert the html contents to plain text and if url points to file (e.g; PDF) or image, it would download those in a folder.

I also have to scrape dynamically loaded content(javascript) so, as per [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html#pre-rendering-javascript), I integrated [scrapy_splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash). But, my spider could not perform recursive crawl, hence I referred [github issue](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash/issues/92) for solution and I got it working by adding changes suggested [here](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash/issues/92#issuecomment-487113695).

But, scrapy_splash does not download any files(e.g; pdf) or images, it only scrapes html content. And due my limited knowledge(zero) of scrapy_splash I am not able to figure out the solution (not sure if there is one). Is there a fix or maybe a reliable workaround for my problem.

My Code:

**../spiders/my_spider.py:**

```
from os.path import splitext
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy_project import utility
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest, SplashJsonResponse, SplashTextResponse

IGNORE_IMAGE_FILES = False
IGNORE_FILES = False  # do/don't ignore non-text file
IGNORE_TEXT_FILE = False
ENGLISH_LANG_CODE = 'en'
FOLLOW = True
image_extensions = utility.get_extensions_for_type('image')


class CustomLinkExtractor(LinkExtractor):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomLinkExtractor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.deny_extensions = [".zip", ".mp4", ".mp3"]  # ignore files with mentioned extensions


class WebScraper(CrawlSpider):
    name = "myspider"

    start_urls = [
        "https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/file-sample_150kB.pdf"
    ]


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.rules = (Rule(CustomLinkExtractor(), follow=FOLLOW, callback="parse_file",
                           process_request="use_splash"),)
        utility.mkdirs(utility.dir_mapper.values())
        super(WebScraper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def _requests_to_follow(self, response):
        if not isinstance(response, (HtmlResponse, SplashJsonResponse, SplashTextResponse)):
            return
        seen = set()
        for n, rule in enumerate(self._rules):
            links = [lnk for lnk in rule.link_extractor.extract_links(response)
                     if lnk not in seen]
            if links and rule.process_links:
                links = rule.process_links(links)
            for link in links:
                seen.add(link)
                r = self._build_request(n, link)
                yield rule.process_request(r)

    def use_splash(self, request):
        request.meta.update(splash={
            'args': {
                'wait': 1,
            },
            'endpoint': 'render.html',
        })
        return request

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse, endpoint='render.html', args={'wait': 0.5})

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        return self.parse_file(response)

    def parse_file(self, response):
        try:
            def get_title():
                return response.xpath('//title//text()').extract_first()

            file_name = utility.get_file_name(response.url)
            _, extension = splitext(file_name)
            if not IGNORE_TEXT_FILE and (not splitext(response.url)[1].strip() or splitext(response.url)[1].lower() in ['.html', '.htm']) and hasattr(response, "text"):
                pub_content_revision = response.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'pup-content-revision')]/text()").extract()
                title = get_title()
                utility.process_text_response(response.url, file_name, response.body, response.headers,pub_content_revision=pub_content_revision, title=title)
            elif extension in image_extensions:
                if not IGNORE_IMAGE_FILES:
                    yield {'image_urls': [response.url]}
            elif not IGNORE_FILES and 'text/html' not in utility.get_response_type(response.headers):
                yield {'file_urls': [response.url]}

        except Exception as ex:
            self.logger.error(ex, exc_info=True)
```

**Splash related settings in settings.py:**

```
# Enable or disable downloader middlewares
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    # 'scrapy_project.middlewares.ScrapyFeaturesDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
    'scrapy_project.middlewares.FilterResponses': 300,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
}

SPLASH_URL = 'http://localhost:8050/'

DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'

HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'

# Enable or disable spider middlewares
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
}
```

**Scrapy logs:**

```
020-06-22 14:00:33 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.1.0 started (bot: scrapy_project)
2020-06-22 14:00:33 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.0.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.7.5 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:50:52) - [GCC 8.3.0], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020), cryptography 2.9.2, Platform Linux-***-Ubuntu-18.04-***
2020-06-22 14:00:33 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor
2020-06-22 14:00:33 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'AJAXCRAWL_ENABLED': True,
 'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED': True,
 'BOT_NAME': 'scrapy_project',
 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 30,
 'COOKIES_ENABLED': False,
 'DOWNLOAD_MAXSIZE': 5242880,
 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter',
 'HTTPCACHE_STORAGE': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'scrapy_project.spiders',
 'REACTOR_THREADPOOL_MAXSIZE': 20,
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['scrapy_project.spiders']}
2020-06-22 14:00:33 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: *************
2020-06-22 14:00:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.throttle.AutoThrottle']
2020-06-22 14:00:33 [py.warnings] WARNING: /home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/crawl.py:135: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Rule.process_request should accept two arguments (request, response), accepting only one is deprecated
  self._rules[-1]._compile(self)
2020-06-22 14:00:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy_project.middlewares.FilterResponses',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.ajaxcrawl.AjaxCrawlMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-06-22 14:00:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-06-22 14:00:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['scrapy_project.pipelines.MyFilesPipeline']
2020-06-22 14:00:33 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-06-22 14:00:33 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-06-22 14:00:33 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-06-22 14:00:33 [py.warnings] WARNING: /home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy_splash/request.py:41: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function to_native_str. Use to_unicode instead.
  url = to_native_str(url)
2020-06-22 14:00:34 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://file-examples.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-06-22 14:00:34 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://localhost:8050/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-06-22 14:00:40 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/file-sample_150kB.pdf via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times): 502 Bad Gateway
2020-06-22 14:00:47 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/file-sample_150kB.pdf via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (failed 2 times): 502 Bad Gateway
2020-06-22 14:00:52 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] ERROR: Gave up retrying <GET https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/file-sample_150kB.pdf via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (failed 3 times): 502 Bad Gateway
2020-06-22 14:00:52 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (502) <GET https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/file-sample_150kB.pdf via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (referer: None)
2020-06-22 14:00:52 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <502 https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/file-sample_150kB.pdf>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2020-06-22 14:00:52 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-06-22 14:00:52 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 2132,
 'downloader/request_count': 5,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 3,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 1734,
 'downloader/response_count': 5,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/502': 3,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 19.507311,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 22, 8, 30, 52, 877442),
 'httperror/response_ignored_count': 1,
 'httperror/response_ignored_status_count/502': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 5,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 14,
 'log_count/WARNING': 2,
 'memusage/max': 1420165120,
 'memusage/startup': 1420165120,
 'response_received_count': 3,
 'retry/count': 2,
 'retry/max_reached': 1,
 'retry/reason_count/502 Bad Gateway': 2,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/404': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 4,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 4,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 4,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 4,
 'splash/render.html/request_count': 1,
 'splash/render.html/response_count/502': 3,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 22, 8, 30, 33, 370131)}
2020-06-22 14:00:52 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I know I am missing something, any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Maybe switching from `IGNORE_IMAGE_FILES=True` from `IGNORE_IMAGE_FILES=False`?

Comment: Hi @Arount, I was actually testing if the script downloads only files (e.g; .pdf, .doc, etc) and I was intentionally ignoring images. That's  why I had set `IGNORE_IMAGE_FILES=True` and it failed. I have reset it to False